# Discord.py Bot sends weird embed text instead of embed

Tags: python, discord.py

```py
@bot.event
async def on_message(message):
    embed = discord.Embed(
        title = "anything",
        description = f"كت تويت : \n {message.content} \n ||@here||"
        )

    if message.channel.id == 927235996158922802:
        channelO = await bot.fetch_channel(926945495413301290)
        await channelO.send(embed)
```

In this code, the bot sends me this text message `<discord.embeds.Embed object at 0x0000019E83E31D80>` instead of the embed. There are no errors.

Comment: https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html#discord.GroupChannel.send

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change your last line to:

```py
await channelO.send(embed=embed)
```

It's happening because when you don't add argument `embed=, files=, etc.` it automatically takes it as `content=` which is for text messages. So, `discord.py` converts your embed to `string` and sends it like a text message.

[Check out documentation](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html#discord.GroupChannel.send)